# Passar variaveis como parametro ao carregar a pagina

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tenho uma function que marca o local onde foi dado um clique do mouse, pondo um circulo vermelho no clic e salvando as coordenadas de onde ocorreu este clic.

Script que exibe a posição do mouse quando efetuado click na página.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).click(function(e){
        document.getElementById('coord').value =( e.pageX + ":" + e.pageY)
    });
})
```

Script que gera a marcação da local clicado.

```
 function click_pos(e, ele) {
   var x = e.pageX;
   var y = e.pageY;
   circle = document.getElementById('circle');
   circle.style.left = x-15 + 'px';
   circle.style.top = y-152+ 'px';
   circle.style.display = 'block';
 }
```

A forma que é executado a marcação

```
 <div class="row" onclick="click_pos(event, this)" id="ele" >
    <div id="circle"></div>
        <div class="row" id="teste" > </div> 
 </div>
```

Porem preciso que outra pagina quando carregada, pegue as coordenadas enviadas e gere a marcação no local da coordenada X:Y

Consigo passar esta coordenadas sem problemas, mas não estou sabendo fazer como carregar a pagina com a marcação nesta coord.

Comment: QUando clica vai redirecionar para a outra página?

Comment: não... primeiro faço um cadastro, onde entre as informações contidas no form é a coordenada X:Y. E depois recupero estas informações no resultade de uma pesquisa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode gerar um JSON no seu back-end (PHP) e carregá-lo via AJAX na sua página através de uma URL definida por você (que pode mudar de acordo com o ID da página, usuário, etc).

Exemplo (no seu back-end):

```
// Arquivo pegaCoordenadas.php

// Puxa todas as coordenadas de alguma consulta no banco
// e armazena o array na variável $coordenadas, exemplo:
$resultado = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM coordenadas WHERE ..."));
$coordenadas = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);

// Retorna essas coordenadas em formato JSON para a requisição AJAX
echo json_encode($coordenadas);
```

E no seu client-side:

```
//retornaria algo como {x: 105, y: 387}
$.getJSON('pegaCoordenadas.php', gerarMarcacoes); 

function gerarMarcacoes(coordenadas) {
    var x = coordenadas.x;
    var y = coordenadas.y;

    circle = document.getElementById('circle');
    circle.style.left = x-15 + 'px';
    circle.style.top = y-152+ 'px';
    circle.style.display = 'block';
}
```

O que esse código estará fazendo é basicamente efetuar uma requisição AJAX que retorne as coordenadas que você deseja, e após o retorno destas coordenadas, você pode usá-las em uma outra função (`gerarMarcacoes()`) para criar a marcação na sua página.

Comment: desculpe a ignorância, mas não entendi a parte do back-end.

Comment: @FelipeOliveira a ideia é que você crie uma URL que sempre que acessada, acesse o banco de dados e retorne as coordenadas em formato JSON (para ser lido pelo JavaScript no lado cliente).

Comment: Após isto você pode acessar esse arquivo através do seu cliente e usar os dados retornados pelo seu arquivo PHP para gerar o círculo no local indicado. Editei o código na resposta para tentar deixar mais claro.

Comment: no momento ta funcionando da seguinte maneira: primeiro faço um cadastro, onde entre as informações contidas no form é a coordenada X:Y. Depois recupero estas informações como resultado de uma pesquisa, na pagina view.php, onde eu gostaria que ja carregase com a marcação. Da forma como vc esta informando, teria que ter outra pagina somente para a alocação dos resultados da query  e depois acessalos pelo view.php?

Comment: @FelipeOliveira Exato. Mas como no seu caso já existe uma página PHP retornando esses dados (view.php) o que você pode fazer é "embutir" essas informações nela própria (adicionando um atributo em algum elemento HTML, ex: `<div id="coordenadas" data-x="<?php echo $x ?>" data-y="<?php echo $y ?>"></div>`. Quando a página for renderizada, é só usar o JavaScript para pegar essas informações deste elemento e aplicar na própria página.

Comment: vergonhoso (da minha parte)... não estou conseguindo fazer com que funcione. Estou errando em algum momento ou não sabendo fazer mesmo!  :(

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43433/discussion-between-kazzkiq-and-felipe-oliveira).